# Using future perfect with an adverb of the past

Tags: grammar, future-perfect

the sentence states
[image]

> Now some of you won't have been to Park Hill before , so let me
>   explain about our facility

would you please explain how the writer used future perfect with " before "

Comment: The adverb is a red herring. 'Now some of you won't have been to Park Hill, so let me explain about our facility.' works in exactly the same way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That *won't* does not signify futurity: it's an 'epistemic' use of *will* to signify inferential certainty. Compare:

> **A**: Mom, there's somebody in the garage.
>   **B**: Oh, that **will be** the boy I hired to mow the lawn.

In paraphrase, the speaker is saying

> I'm sure there are some of you who haven't been here before.